# Redirecting to another network

Tags: linux, networking

I am working on putting together a test version of a linux configuration. I want to put this test configuration on a different network than the normal configuration.

- Normal network: **192.168.50.***
- Test network: **192.168.150.***

I want to achieve this without making any changes to the software settings that is on the configuration.

My approach to achieving this is to change the network interface to connect to the test network, and redirect all outgoing calls. E.g. redirect **192.168.50.10** to **192.168.150.10**

I do this by using iptables.

> iptables -t nat -A OUTPUT -d 192.168.50.10 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.150.10

This works as intended, if I change the *NETMASK* on the interface from **255.255.255.0** to **255.255.0.0**.
If I do not change the *NETMASK* I get this when I type in the normal network address.

> connect: Network is unreachable

Changing the *NETMASK* is unfortunately not an option.

That being said, my question is this; Is there a way to get around the *NETMASK* issue, or is there a better way to achieve what I want to do?

Answer (score 0):

I implemented a workaround for this issue.

I did this by adding a virtual network connection to the normal network, and then route all the traffic to the test network interface.

*Network interfaces and IPs:*

- Test network: **bond0 - 192.168.150.***
- Normal network: **bond0:0 - 192.168.50.***

*Routing command:*

> iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o bond0 -j SNAT --to-source 192.168.150.10

This solution gets the job done, but it is not ideal. It bypasses the "Network is unreachable" issue, but I would have preferred to have no connection to the normal network from the test hosts.